# Altering Loop count

Tags: text-processing

I have multiple code files with lot of loops. Now I have to change all the loop counts to 4 times the current count in all the files. Is there a way I can achieve this for all the files simultaneously.

Loop looks like:

```
RUN FOR 300;
```

The count (300) changes for each loop.

Comment: Do you want to change `run for x` into `run for 4*x`?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us examples of the text files you want to edit and the output you would like to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quadrupling all numbers in a single file that appear in the form, `RUN FOR <N>;`, where `<N>` is any number, could be done with Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(\bRUN FOR )(\d+)(;)/ $1 . 4*$2 . $3 /ge;' codefile
```

Look up the sections on "Metacharacters" and "Assertions" in [Perl regular expressions manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) if you need to match the beginning of line or some such.

This could probably be done with, say `awk` too, if we knew the input format more exactly.

<sub>(Though, I do suspect that from a program structuring standpoint this method of modifying a program isn't among the neatest.)</sub>

Comment: Don't really need the other capture groups `perl -pe 's/\bRUN FOR \K\d+/4*$&/ge;'`